# Update Field schema in Django Model

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to update a field key from the following in the model:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True)
```

to:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = False)
```

However I need to update the mysql db without losing any of the current data. How would I go about doing this? I tried `$ python manage.py syncdb` but it doesn't seem to update the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `syncdb` [doesn't do that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb). It only creates new tables, but doesn't change the existing if your model changes.

On a dev environment, to update your database after changing your model, you can use `python manage.py reset appname` to empty out your database, and use `syncdb` again.

Otherwise, you have to use tools such as [South](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/about.html). South was made to handle migrations, but also changing the database when the model changes.

There is also [django-evolutions](http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/) that does just what you want, but I still recommend South as its migrations features are almost always going to be of some use.

Comment: hmm. what are the pros and cons to South and django-evolutions in your opinion? South seems much harder to learn...

Comment: django-evolutions does just what you want to do in your question, while South is much more evolved and also allows you to do migrations easily (once you get the hang of it). But yeah, the drawback is that it's more complicated than django-evolutions to use.

Comment: Also I just found out that South doesn't support all mysql migrations (tried to use it in the above example and found the docs here: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/databaseapi.html#database-specific-issues. Do you know if django-evolutions does?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) and remove the unique index from this field.

Comment: you're saying to run some sql to manually make the change? if I do this do i have to simultaneously change the model in django framework?

Comment: Its not really running sql commands, its a web interface to manage your db.

Comment: i understand, but i'm not using php so i dont have that.